# Good GameBoy Advance Emulator?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Is there any good GameBoy Advance Emulator for ubuntu which supports loading gameshark or action replay saves?

Comment: please explain why the suggestions here are not what you need: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87030/game-console-emulators-nintendo-super-nintendo-sega-genesis-nintendo-64-gam

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/gngb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most known GBA emulator is VisualBoyAdvance (as the link that fossfreedom posted says). The problem is that it lacks of some important features. The good news is that it exists a fork: [Visual Boy Advance-M](http://vba-m.com/).

It supports loading Gameshark, action replay saves and a lot more. (I specially like the option to use smart filters when scaling the game).

**No filter**

[image]

**hq2x filter**

[image]

You can install it from [PlayDeb.net](http://www.playdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/11.10/?q=vba).
The bad news is that PlayDeb hasn't updated their packages to Precise Pangolin (12.04). But I think that installing the [oneiric package](http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/playdeb_0.3-1~getdeb1_all.deb) should work perfectly.

After you install the PlayDeb package, you will only have to install the following package: `vbam-gtk`

---

EDIT: Right now, PlayDeb packages are available from 9.10 to 13.04 (the packages have not been updated yet to 13.10). As always, if you use 13.10, in most cases, you can use 13.04 (or any other version) packages without experiencing any problems (if any, it will be because of dependencies, which is very unlikely), as well as 13.04 repository.

Comment: It supports .xps saves?

Comment: I have not personally tried it, but it apparently you only have to rename the .xps file to .sgm and go to Emulation>Load State>From File... in order to load it.

Comment: Doesent work @Alfredo

Comment: Wow, I'm really sorry. Old snapshots use to have the option to load Gameshark saves (i.e. xps and sps files), but somehow new versions of VBA-M don't! I've also noticed that the original VBA (wich is  available as visualboyadvance-gtk package) has lost the option to import Gameshark Saves. Apparently there's no way to deal with .xps files on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Downloading it right now. I will tell you how it works

Comment: @Diego I hope it works great for you ;)

Comment: I couldn't install it. It saids that the vbam-gtk doesn't exist

Comment: That's very strange. May I know which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: VBA had the too fast bug when I tried it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62611/visual-boy-advanced-emulator-runs-too-fast

Comment: If you haven't noticed already, VBA-M on PlayDeb is already available on 13.10 and 14.04 as well. The PlayDeb team usually release VBA-M for new Ubuntu versions when the Ubuntu version in question gets an official release version.

Answer (score 1):

On 12.04:

- VBA 1.8.0 `sudo apt-get install visualboyadvance-gtk` had the run too fast bug which made it unplayable for me: [Visual boy advanced emulator runs too fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62611/visual-boy-advanced-emulator-runs-too-fast)
- Mednafen 0.8.D.3 `sudo apt-get install mednafen` worked well, but has no nice GUI config.

  Hit F1 for basic help, ALT+SHIFT+1 to configure controller 1.

  backtick `` ` `` to fast forward. To change it to space: edit `~/.mednafen/mednafen.cfg` line `command.fast_forward` to  `command.fast_forward keyboard 32`.

  `keyboard` values seems to follow http://expandinghead.net/keycode.html