# VisualBoyAdvance emulator only returns a blank screen

Tags: software-installation, emulation

I recently installed Visual boy advance from the software center. And I downloaded a romhack and whenever I  open it with VBA the only thing that happens is I get a blank screen on VBA with a percentage at the top. I read on a different question to try using Mednafen. So, I went and installed that and got the same result. So, if anybody has any kind of advice to help me out here it would be much appreciated.

Comment: See if this [answer about using PlayDeb packages](http://askubuntu.com/a/113757/89515) helps at all.