# Up-to-date game boy emulators?

Tags: emulation

I am looking for an up-to-date gameboy emulator for ubuntu. All of the forums I have read are old and most of the projects they list are not supported for the new ubuntu versions. Does anyone know of a gameboy emulator?

I just want to play pokemon.

Comment: I use visualboy advanced, it's on the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

VisualBoy Advance is the best I've found. It's the simplest to install and run. You can find it here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/visualboyadvance-gtk/.

Here is a guide I found to run old Gameboy Color games in color. I have not personally tested this guide, but this user does capture Gameboy games for internet posting using this method (they're in color): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p37UfVSzcrY

Answer (score 0):

Visual Boy Advance (VBA) on Ubuntu repository isn't up-to-date, as evidenced by [framerate issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62611/visual-boy-advanced-emulator-runs-too-fast/).

You can use [RetroArch](http://www.libretro.com/) with **Gambatte** core, which is much more accurate than VBA.
According to the tests done by [TASVideos](http://tasvideos.org/EmulatorResources/GBAccuracyTests.html), Gambatte can pass 89.4% of the accuracy test while VBA can only pass 38.3% of it.

Precompiled packages of RetroArch and Gambatte core are available [in this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hunter-kaller/+archive/ppa) for Ubuntu 12.04 through 14.04 (for 14.04 and newer versions, please use [this PPA instead](https://launchpad.net/~libretro/+archive/ubuntu/stable)). Package name for emulator itself is "retroarch" and Gambatte core is "libretro-gambatte".

Answer (score 0):

Vouch for Retroarch. The [1.7.1](https://www.gamulator.com/downloads/emulators/RetroArch.7z) version supports all controllers and game pads, has a save/load option and can even load games from the early Game Boy and Game Boy Color versions. It supports more games than VBA and the accuracy is higher.